# Can I connect a openCart project with mobile app?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mobile, opencart

my English doesn't well, I am sorry

I have a open Cart project this project have own database,
and I have mobile app for the same project but have the own database can I connect the two project with by one database ?
I want to connect the web open Cart app with mobile app by the database of mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have OpenCart and other application's tables in the same database.

The [OpenCart](http://docs.opencart.com/en-gb/installation/) Step 3 has "prefix". This sets the prefix of the table names to eliminate conflicts with other applications in the same database.

A better way is put your mobile app in its own database.

The mobile app can access OpenCart by prefixing the table names in SQL by the opencart database. For example:

```
SELECT user FROM opencartdb.oc_users
```

Comment: Databases don't have dashboards. I know you are trying to refer to some GUI. Try the SQL.